# How do I import module from one go project(Common) to other go project (API)?

Tags: go, github, import

I have a go project where the common functionality is implemented , and there is an another go project for the API which uses common functionality from the first project. API project uses the common project , the imports are done from git hub.

I have added a new functionality to the common project and trying to access that new functionality in API project . I have pushed the code to my branch in git hub (new code not there in master branch of common project) . How can I import the new functionality to API project

Comment: Did you go through an of the entry-level tutorials which explain this, like: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started and https://go.dev/doc/code? If the terminology is confusing you, you don't import modules, you import packages which are contained within modules. Unless the "common" package in your case would be used by other independent projects, you probably only want a single module.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `go get -u github.com/yourcommonproject`. From `go help get`:

```
The -u flag instructs get to update modules providing dependencies
of packages named on the command line to use newer minor or patch
releases when available.
```

The `-x` flag might also be useful in debugging:

```
The -x flag prints commands as they are executed. This is useful for
debugging version control commands when a module is downloaded directly
from a repository.
```

Useful relevant links:

https://golang.cafe/blog/how-to-upgrade-golang-dependencies.html

https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-dependencies